# How to close any window using OS library in python

Tags: python

I coded my own virtual assistant in python. I know how to start apps through my voice via `os.system` or `os.startfile`, but I don't know how to close the current window ?

Comment: I hardly imagine how does your question related to *AI*, *virtual* and *assistant* tags.

Comment: Why not get the process id of the launched window and kill it by invoking taskkill

Comment: but sir, you under stand my question. Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

os.system('taskkill /F /IM *processname*')

e.g:  os.system('taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe')

Comment: That will close all open chrome instances. In case the user want to close any specific window, this will not be able to do it. Instead better approach will be keep track of process id of all the windows that the assistant is opening and kill them using command like `taskkill  /f /pid 1230`

Comment: @Roy Ofcourse it will and in most cases you need  window/process name cuz PID is to specific like chrome creates a new process for every tab and extension so good luck finding PID of the tab you wanna close programmatically

Comment: Indeed, getting PID to a specific instance is difficult in normal situation. But since we are talking about virtual assistant here, I think it will be possible, may be difficult, but possible to keep track of PIDs.